# Clipboard application to share copied data between multiple PCs

Tags: windows, gratis, clipboard

I am looking for a free clipboard software that works on Windows through which I can access the copied data in multiple PCs. What I meant is, if I copied some text in one PC it should be available in another PC. Currently I use [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/), but it has no ability to share clipboard data to another PC.

If anyone is knowing about such a software, please let me know.

Comment: For good, secure and privacy-friendly solutions (if you care about all 3 of them) it might be important to know: Are all affected computers in the same (local) network – or must sharing work over the Internet? Privacy-wise, are cloud-based solutions acceptable (where all you copy will be stored somewhere on "other people's computers" in the process)? Are you talking about text-only, or also other objects (such as images, formatted text etc)? What is your price margin?

Comment: @Izzy I want a free software and most of the time the systems will be in the same network. Answer by Somanor suits my need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1Clipboard can do this for you http://1clipboard.io/ the application at least for Windows is built with ElectronJS the same as Spotify and Slack.

Some features:

Copy here. Paste there.
Synchronize everything you copy and access it from anywhere on any device.

Security that you can trust
Powered by Google, 1Clipboard synchronizes your clipboard through Google Drive™
- proven, secure place to store your private data. All you need to have is a Google Account.

Looking for local clipboard manager?
1Clipboard still works the best with "Offline Mode" if you use only one computer, or if you don't want to synchronize your clipboard. You can toggle this setting on and off anytime.

Comment: "Security that you can trust" – seeing that they're still using a naked HTTP link somehow makes me doubt I can trust their security. And if I would want to share my clipboard with another device of mine, I certainly wouldn't want that to go via Google's cloud. But then, I wouldn't use Windows either :) Just saying, not critisizing your answer. OP didn't specify such details (not even whether the PCs are inside the same network).

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully sure what's your setup. It might be a XY problem, but...

You can use [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy), which is about using a single keyboard and a single mouse towards multiple computers (typically) standing next to each other. Clipboard sharing is just one of the features. More importantly you get one keyboard and mouse pair to control them all.

Moreover, they don't have to use the same operating system.